# select margin don't work

Tags: html, css

I'm working on a registration form and I have a problem when I want to make input["text"] (year) and select item (day and month) on the same line, this what I'm getting :
[registration form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0lE5E.png)
I want to delete the margin on the bottom of the select tag (added by default )  by adding a margin on the top, so I add this :

```css
input[type="email"],
input[type="password"],
input[type="text"],
select {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  height: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  border: none;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #313A3D;
  background-color: #E8E9EA;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/styleAuth.css" />
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <div class="navbartop">
      <!--<a class="title" href="./auth.html" >title of the template</a>-->
      <a class="item selected" href="#auth">Authentification</a>
      <a class="item" href="#register">register</a>
      <a class="item" href="#newsleter">newsleter</a>
      <a class="item" href="#comments">Comments</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <section class="secondSection">
    <div class="registerPanel">
      <div class="row topbuffer">
        <div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" name="fn" placeholder="first name" /> </div>
        <div class="col-md-6"><input type="text" name="ln" placeholder="last name" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row topBuffer">
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <select>
            <option selected="">day</option>
            <option>1...31</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <select>
            <option>month</option>
            <option>1...12</option>
          </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <input type="text" name="y" placeholder="year" />
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="row topBuffer">
        <div class="col-md-12"><input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" /></div>
      </div>
      <div class="row topBuffer">
        <div class="col-md-6"><input type="password" name="pw1" placeholder="enter your password" /></div>
        <div class="col-md-6"><input type="password" name="pw2" placeholder="comfirm your password" /></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>

</body>

</html>
```

... but it's still not working, the margin on the top has no effect, so can anyone help me, guys !!
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

**Updated**:

I do not know if I understood well but what you want is to remove the botton margin of the two selects ?, if so, here is the necessary css:

First, you need to add a `class` to the day and month selects like this:

**HTML**:

```
    <div class="col-md-4">
         <select class="margin-bottom-0">
               <option selected="" >day</option>
               <option>1...31</option>
         </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <select class="margin-bottom-0">
             <option>month</option>
             <option>1...12</option>
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
         <input type="text" name="y" placeholder="year"/> 
    </div>
```

After that do you need to declare the class in css like this:

**CSS**:

```
.margin-bottom-0{
    margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

I hope it helps you

Regards!

Comment: thank you @Radames E. Hernandez D.L.R., but it's still you don't understand the request, I have three items tow of those items (month and day) have margin-bottom by default, what I want is to delete this margin-bottom, not remove the year margin-top

Comment: sorry, no effect! :(

Comment: I was reviewing your case, and the problem is not in the margin-bottom of the day and month fields, because they do not have that property, the problem is that the field of the year has margin-top and is pressing down to generate space below the fields day and month, I think that.

Comment: thank you  Radames E. Hernandez D.L.R. for taken time to respond me , and yes, this because I m adding a margin-top for all input tag, the problem is I add the same margin in the select tag (like you see above ) but the margin is invisible, and if you analyze the image above you gonna see that the align-center of the select tag was ignored to, so all styles of position are ignored, what's the problem ???

Answer (score 0):

Try this. No need to write any css

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head content must come *after* these tags -->
    <title>Test Code</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css " crossorigin="anonymous ">
    <style>
        input[type="email"],
        input[type="password"],
        input[type="text"],
        select {
            /* display : block;
   width : 80%;
   height : 30px;
   text-align : center;
   border : none;
   font-size : 1em;
   color: #313A3D;
   background-color: #E8E9EA;
   margin-top : 10px; */
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <div class="navbartop">
            <!--<a class="title" href="./auth.html" >title of the template</a>-->
            <a class="item selected" href="#auth">Authentification</a>
            <a class="item" href="#register">register</a>
            <a class="item" href="#newsleter">newsleter</a>
            <a class="item" href="#comments">Comments</a>
        </div>
    </header>
    <section class="secondSection">
        <div class="registerPanel">
            <div class="row topbuffer form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" name="fn" placeholder="first name" / class="form-control"> </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="text" name="ln" placeholder="last name" / class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="row topBuffer form-group">
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option selected="">day</option>
                        <option>1...31</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <select class="form-control">
                        <option>month</option>
                        <option>1...12</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <input type="text" name="y" placeholder="year" class="form-control" />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="email" / class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="row form-group">
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="password" name="pw1" placeholder="enter your password" / class="form-control">
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <input type="password" name="pw2" placeholder="comfirm your password" / class="form-control">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

    <!-- jQuery (necessary for Bootstrap's JavaScript plugins) -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: thank you @Sharvan, but is just adding another background color to the select tag, it does not delete the margin.

Comment: j think there is a relationship with the display property

Comment: Can you provide an explanation? A code dump doesn't help anyone understand the problem and how it was solved.

Comment: ok @jhpratt , the problem is the select tag don't obey the margin, position, and the align-text properties, if you see above I added the style to all input and select but just the select tag has broken the rule.

Comment: this a link to the project: https://github.com/ekkatharisi/webDev/tree/master/devWeb/project1